# Ignoring the vertical space occupied by a `tikzpicture`

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a `minipage` environment to the left of a `tikzpicture` environment.  Following these environments, I have three `equation` environments.  There is some extra vertical space because the display from the `tikzpicture` environment occupies more vertical space than that of the `minipage` environment.  How do I get `LaTeX` to ignore the vertical space of the `tikzpicture` environment?  (There is a lot of code here.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

A right circular cone with a base radius and height of $R$ and $H$, respectively, circumscribes another right circular cone with the same axis. Determine the dimensions of the inscribed cone containing the maximum volume.


\noindent \begin{minipage}[t]{4in}
\noindent \textbf{Determination of the requisite dimensions} \vskip1.25mm
\noindent \raggedright{The intersection between the plane containing the axis of the \\
cones and the cones is a pair of isosceles triangles --- one in- \\
scribed in the other so that their altitudes are collinear. The \\
base  radius and altitude of the circumscribing triangle are $R$ \\
and $H$, respectively. If the base radius and altitude of the \\
inscribed triangle are $r$ and $h$, respectively,}
\end{minipage}
%
\hspace{0.5cm}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]

%Two isosceles triangles --- one inscribed in the other so that the bases are parallel, and the
%altitude of the smaller triangle is part of the altitude of the circumscribing triangle.  If the
%altitude and base of the circumscribing isosceles triangle are H and R, respectively, the
%base radius and altitude of the inscribed triangle enclosing the biggest area is r=(2/3)R and
%h=(HR-Hr)/R, respectively. In this diagram, R=3/2 and H=4, and so r=1 and h=4/3.

%The circumscribing isosceles triangle has vertices A, B, and C, and the center of its base AB is
%called O.
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);
%
\path (-3/2,0) coordinate (A) (3/2,0) coordinate (B) (0,4) coordinate (C);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

%The altitude of $\triangle{ABC}$ is drawn.
\draw[dashed] (O) -- (0,4);


%The inscribed isosceles triangle has vertices E, F, and O, and the center of its base EF is
%called P.
\coordinate (P) at (0,4/3);
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
%
\path (-1,4/3) coordinate (E) (1,4/3) coordinate (F);
\draw (E) -- (F) -- (O) -- cycle;


%The labels for the lengths of two congruent sides and the base of the isosceles triangle are typeset.
%
\draw[|<->|] ($($(A) +(-0.45cm,0)$)!-0.5cm!-90:($(A) +(0,4) +(-0.45cm,0)$)$) -- ($($(A) +(0,4) +(-0.45cm,0)$)!-0.5cm!90:($(A) +(-0.45cm,0)$)$);
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($($(A) +(-0.55,0)$)!-0.5cm!-90:($(A) +(0,4) +(-0.55,0)$)$)!0.5!($($(A) +(0,4) +(-0.55,0)$)!-0.5cm!90:($(A) +(-0.55,0)$)$)$){$H$};
%
\draw[|<->|] ($($(A) +(-15pt,0)$)!0.15cm!-90:($(A) +(0,4/3) +(-15pt,0)$)$) -- ($($(A) +(0,4/3) +(-15pt,0)$)!0.15cm!90:($(A) +(-15pt,0)$)$);
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($($(A) +(-0.1,0)$)!0.15cm!-90:($(A) +(0,4/3) +(-0.1,0)$)$)!0.5!($($(A) +(0,4/3) +(-0.1,0)$)!0.15cm!90:($(A) +(-0.1,0)$)$)$){$h$};
%
\path node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(A)!0.5!(O)$) +(0,-0.1)$){$R$};
%
\path node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(0,4/3)!0.5!(-1,4/3)$) +(0,0.1)$){$r$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{equation*}
\frac{H - h}{r} = \frac{H}{R} .
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
HR - hR = Hr .
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
h = \frac{HR - Hr}{R} .
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `tikzpicture` into a `\raisebox` that sets the height and depth of the picture to zero.

```
\raisebox{0mm}[0mm][0mm]%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
   ...
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
```

See the [LaTeX Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#raisebox) for the details of `\raisebox`.

Answer (score 3):

Just place the equations in the minipage:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

A right circular cone with a base radius and height of $R$ and $H$, 
respectively, circumscribes another right circular cone with the 
same axis. Determine the dimensions of the inscribed cone containing 
the maximum volume.

\medskip

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{4in}
\textbf{Determination of the requisite dimensions}

\medskip

The intersection between the plane containing the axis of the
cones and the cones is a pair of isosceles triangles --- one 
inscribed in the other so that their altitudes are collinear. 
The base  radius and altitude of the circumscribing triangle 
are $R$ and $H$, respectively. If the base radius and altitude 
of the inscribed triangle are $r$ and $h$, respectively,
\begin{gather*}
\frac{H - h}{r} = \frac{H}{R} . \\
HR - hR = Hr . \\
h = \frac{HR - Hr}{R} .
\end{gather*}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]

%Two isosceles triangles --- one inscribed in the other so that the bases are parallel, and the
%altitude of the smaller triangle is part of the altitude of the circumscribing triangle.  If the
%altitude and base of the circumscribing isosceles triangle are H and R, respectively, the
%base radius and altitude of the inscribed triangle enclosing the biggest area is r=(2/3)R and
%h=(HR-Hr)/R, respectively. In this diagram, R=3/2 and H=4, and so r=1 and h=4/3.

%The circumscribing isosceles triangle has vertices A, B, and C, and the center of its base AB is
%called O.
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);
%
\path (-3/2,0) coordinate (A) (3/2,0) coordinate (B) (0,4) coordinate (C);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

%The altitude of $\triangle{ABC}$ is drawn.
\draw[dashed] (O) -- (0,4);


%The inscribed isosceles triangle has vertices E, F, and O, and the center of its base EF is
%called P.
\coordinate (P) at (0,4/3);
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
%
\path (-1,4/3) coordinate (E) (1,4/3) coordinate (F);
\draw (E) -- (F) -- (O) -- cycle;


%The labels for the lengths of two congruent sides and the base of the isosceles triangle are typeset.
%
\draw[|<->|] ($($(A) +(-0.45cm,0)$)!-0.5cm!-90:($(A) +(0,4) +(-0.45cm,0)$)$) -- ($($(A) +(0,4) +(-0.45cm,0)$)!-0.5cm!90:($(A) +(-0.45cm,0)$)$);
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($($(A) +(-0.55,0)$)!-0.5cm!-90:($(A) +(0,4) +(-0.55,0)$)$)!0.5!($($(A) +(0,4) +(-0.55,0)$)!-0.5cm!90:($(A) +(-0.55,0)$)$)$){$H$};
%
\draw[|<->|] ($($(A) +(-15pt,0)$)!0.15cm!-90:($(A) +(0,4/3) +(-15pt,0)$)$) -- ($($(A) +(0,4/3) +(-15pt,0)$)!0.15cm!90:($(A) +(-15pt,0)$)$);
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($($(A) +(-0.1,0)$)!0.15cm!-90:($(A) +(0,4/3) +(-0.1,0)$)$)!0.5!($($(A) +(0,4/3) +(-0.1,0)$)!0.15cm!90:($(A) +(-0.1,0)$)$)$){$h$};
%
\path node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(A)!0.5!(O)$) +(0,-0.1)$){$R$};
%
\path node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(0,4/3)!0.5!(-1,4/3)$) +(0,0.1)$){$r$};

\end{tikzpicture}\hspace*{-1in}

\bigskip

A filler. A right circular cone with a base radius and height of $R$ and $H$, 
respectively, circumscribes another right circular cone with the 
same axis. Determine the dimensions of the inscribed cone containing 
the maximum volume.


\end{document}
```

I guessed you want the picture to stick in the margin.

[image]

Alternatively, use `wrapfig`; check the package documentation for the meaning of the arguments to `\begin{wrapfigure}`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

A right circular cone with a base radius and height of $R$ and $H$, 
respectively, circumscribes another right circular cone with the 
same axis. Determine the dimensions of the inscribed cone containing 
the maximum volume.

\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{r}{1in}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]

%Two isosceles triangles --- one inscribed in the other so that the bases are parallel, and the
%altitude of the smaller triangle is part of the altitude of the circumscribing triangle.  If the
%altitude and base of the circumscribing isosceles triangle are H and R, respectively, the
%base radius and altitude of the inscribed triangle enclosing the biggest area is r=(2/3)R and
%h=(HR-Hr)/R, respectively. In this diagram, R=3/2 and H=4, and so r=1 and h=4/3.

%The circumscribing isosceles triangle has vertices A, B, and C, and the center of its base AB is
%called O.
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);
%
\path (-3/2,0) coordinate (A) (3/2,0) coordinate (B) (0,4) coordinate (C);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

%The altitude of $\triangle{ABC}$ is drawn.
\draw[dashed] (O) -- (0,4);


%The inscribed isosceles triangle has vertices E, F, and O, and the center of its base EF is
%called P.
\coordinate (P) at (0,4/3);
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
%
\path (-1,4/3) coordinate (E) (1,4/3) coordinate (F);
\draw (E) -- (F) -- (O) -- cycle;


%The labels for the lengths of two congruent sides and the base of the isosceles triangle are typeset.
%
\draw[|<->|] ($($(A) +(-0.45cm,0)$)!-0.5cm!-90:($(A) +(0,4) +(-0.45cm,0)$)$) -- ($($(A) +(0,4) +(-0.45cm,0)$)!-0.5cm!90:($(A) +(-0.45cm,0)$)$);
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($($(A) +(-0.55,0)$)!-0.5cm!-90:($(A) +(0,4) +(-0.55,0)$)$)!0.5!($($(A) +(0,4) +(-0.55,0)$)!-0.5cm!90:($(A) +(-0.55,0)$)$)$){$H$};
%
\draw[|<->|] ($($(A) +(-15pt,0)$)!0.15cm!-90:($(A) +(0,4/3) +(-15pt,0)$)$) -- ($($(A) +(0,4/3) +(-15pt,0)$)!0.15cm!90:($(A) +(-15pt,0)$)$);
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($($(A) +(-0.1,0)$)!0.15cm!-90:($(A) +(0,4/3) +(-0.1,0)$)$)!0.5!($($(A) +(0,4/3) +(-0.1,0)$)!0.15cm!90:($(A) +(-0.1,0)$)$)$){$h$};
%
\path node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(A)!0.5!(O)$) +(0,-0.1)$){$R$};
%
\path node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($($(0,4/3)!0.5!(-1,4/3)$) +(0,0.1)$){$r$};

\end{tikzpicture}\hspace*{-2in}
\end{wrapfigure}

\noindent\textbf{Determination of the requisite dimensions}

\medskip

\noindent
The intersection between the plane containing the axis of the
cones and the cones is a pair of isosceles triangles --- one 
inscribed in the other so that their altitudes are collinear. 
The base  radius and altitude of the circumscribing triangle 
are $R$ and $H$, respectively. If the base radius and altitude 
of the inscribed triangle are $r$ and $h$, respectively,
\begin{gather*}
\frac{H - h}{r} = \frac{H}{R} . \\
HR - hR = Hr . \\
h = \frac{HR - Hr}{R} .
\end{gather*}

A filler. A right circular cone with a base radius and height of $R$ and $H$, 
respectively, circumscribes another right circular cone with the 
same axis. Determine the dimensions of the inscribed cone containing 
the maximum volume.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have other equations on the page in `display` mode.  If I put the equations in the `minipage` environment, they would not be centered with respect to the margins ... as the other equations on the page.  Sorry.  I forgot to mention that detail.  (gernot suggested using the `\raisebox` command.)

Comment: @Adelyn Well, the `wrapfig` solution does it; I'm not sure if I like it, though.